# Remove dollar sign and convert price to specified format

Tags: java, regex

I am having a string of this type :

String price="$34.56 - $98.45" or it can be simply "$34.56"

I want to convert this string to 34.56-98.45 and 34.56 respectively.

Whats best and easiest way to do it in Java . I was trying for some regex but could not come up.

Comment: `string.replaceAll("\\s*\\$", "")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Shouldn't that be `[\s$]`, to catch the space before the hyphen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with this regex:**

```
String val=price.replaceAll("[^\\P{Punct}-.]+", "");
//[^\\P...] (negated character class of characters not having the property)
```